# How to read value inside a Database View?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, view

I have the below view.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_myview AS
SELECT
emp_joining_dt,
emp_joining_dt+365 as emp_reminder_dt
FROM EMP
/
```

After 1 year of employee's joining, a reminder need to be sent. Daily job reads `emp_reminder_dt` and triggers it.

365 days is mostly constant. But, the requirement is that the company might wish to change it to 183 or 730.

So, the value 365 is configured in a table and read from DB.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_myview AS
SELECT
emp_joining_dt,
emp_joining_dt+MyPackage.get_reminder_days as emp_reminder_dt
FROM EMP
/
```

The problem with above approach is that everytime the view is queried it makes a call to database
to read the value from the configuration table.

Concern has been raised that frequent query to Database should be avoided.

Is there a way to read the value 365 1st time from DB and then on from some cache.
Then when the value is changed, read 1st time from DB and then on from some cache?

Using cache was just my guess but is there any other way?

Comment: frequent query ? You're running this once a day how is that frequent ? Why r u using a package - just join to the table where this value is stored.

Comment: Looking up one row in a table should not be a particular burden in most queries.

Comment: No matter what you do, it's already reading from table `EMP` which is going to be WAY more costly than reading from table `MyPackage` with it's single row and column. I wouldn't waste another second worrying about it.

Comment: _" a reminder need to be sent."_, then this is obviously part of some scheduled procedure. So make the term an input paramter, set as a property of the scheduling of the procedure.  Though as others say, your concern about "frequent query" is sorely misplaced.  This one query, to get a single row from a table, once a day, is less than trivial for the database.

Comment: The lookup function you have seems reasonable. Is it declared as deterministic, parallel enabled and with pragma UDF? (Long and interesting conversations can be had about whether this is abuse of "deterministic", as it is not, but I'd use it here for the statement-level caching.) You could try `result_cache` but I'm not sure it'll be any faster than querying the table using the standard caching.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a special table for changing parameters. One of the easiest way looks like this ([SCD type 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row)):

```sql
create table emp_reminder_dt(
   emp_reminder_dt int,
   modified_dt date default sysdate,
   active varchar2(1 byte) not null check(active in ('Y','N')),
   active_uniq varchar2(1) invisible generated always as (case when active='Y' then 'Y' end),
   constraint c_active_uniq unique (active_uniq)
);
```

So you could have always one active record: invisible column `active_uniq` (and unique constraint on it) doesn't allow to have more than 1 active record.

Then just insert your current value:

```sql
insert into emp_reminder_dt(emp_reminder_dt,active)
  values(365, 'Y');
commit;
```

Now you can easily get active value:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_myview AS
SELECT
emp_joining_dt,
emp_joining_dt
 + (select r.emp_reminder_dt 
    from emp_reminder_dt r 
    where r.active_uniq='Y'
   ) 
  as emp_reminder_dt
FROM EMP
```

Later you can easily change active row to `active='N'` and add new record with new value, so you will have a simple history of changes.

Moreover, you can use other SCD types to allow different values for different time intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Any reasonable application has perhaps dozens of these 1off items that you do not want to hard code a value. For these I generally create a `General_Parameters` table. It is a generalization of the suggestion by @SayanMalakshinov. Something along the lines of:

```
create table general_parameters(
             parm_name    varchar2(64)
           , parm_integer integer 
           , parm_date    date
           , parm_text    varchar2(4000) 
           -- other parameter types
           , constraint general_parameters_pk
                        primary key (parm_name)  
           ); 

insert into general_parameters(parm_name, parm_integer) 
     values ('emp reminder interval',365);
```

Creating the view then is:

```
create or replace view emp_reminder_view as
   select emp_id
        , emp_joining_dt 
        , emp_joining_dt
           + (select parm_integer
                from general_parameters
               where parm_name = 'emp reminder interval'
             )
            as emp_reminder_dt
    from emp;
```

Changing the reminder interval is a simple matter of updating a table entry.  
Note: Added emp_id to view as 2 dates without any qualifier becomes useless in a hurry.

Comment: When `emp_reminder_view` is queried in a `SELECT` then it hits the `general_parameters` table to fetch the data from DB. I am looking for a way where it doesn't hit the DB everytime the view is queried. Is it possible that only when view is compiled it gets the value from DB and further query fetches result without hitting DB?

Comment: You are **already hitting the DB** when you select from the view itself. It hits the underlying table? How do you think a view is populated? Further the view **is not** accessed at compile time. A view is nothing but a stored query.